# How to work with generic <T> with EntitySet<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, entity

I have a opteration that needs to run on three types of EntitySets; however, the data for each type is the same. Linq-to-SQL is creating these three types to match up with a few between, "tween" tables in my database.

Is there a way to work with generic EntitySet types like I've got them below?

```
private EntitySet<T> GetClientHorizontal(EntitySet<T> clientHorizontal) {}
```

It is to solve the redundant issue like below.

```
private EntitySet<LeafHorizontal> 
   GetClientLeafHorizontal(EntitySet<LeafHorizontal> clientLeafHorizontal) { }

private EntitySet<BayHorizontal>
   GetClientBayHorizontal(EntitySet<BayHorizontal> clientBayHorizontal) { }

private EntitySet<SideliteHorizontal>
   GetClientSideliteHorizontal(
      EntitySet<SideliteHorizontal> clientSideliteHorizontal) { }
```

Comment: Can you define a base class for LeafHorizontal, BayHorizontal and SideliteHorizontal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying that these three classes are almost the same - then you can create an interface or base class with common members:

```
interface IHorizontal
{
  int SuperValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to inherit LeafHorizontal, BayHorizontal and SideliteHorizontal classes from this interface:

```
public partial class LeafHorizontal : IHorizontal { ... }
public partial class BayHorizontal : IHorizontal { ... }
public partial class SideliteHorizontal : IHorizontal { ... }
```

After that you can create generic method:

```
private EntitySet<T> GetClientBayHorizontal(EntitySet<T> clientBayHorizontal)  where T : IHorizontal 
{
    clientBayHorizontal.SuperValue++;
}
```

Comment: The Interface approach is the perfect solution for what I asked. Thank you.